# Delete directory indirectly inside of itself

Tags: filesystem

I have a directory inside itself. How do I delete it.

```
~/.local/share/Trash/files$ ls devices/
reg-dummy
~/.local/share/Trash/files$ ls devices/reg-dummy/
subsystem
~/.local/share/Trash/files$ ls devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/
devices
```

Also

```
~/.local/share/Trash/files$ find devices/ | head -n 20
devices/
devices/reg-dummy
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices
devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/reg-dummy
```

Also, although my brain can't solve the halting problem, it appears that `sudo rm -rf devices` goes on forever without producing output.

```
~/.local/share/Trash/files$ sudo rm -rf devices
^C~/.local/share/Trash/files$
```

Same thing for `perl -e 'use File::Path qw(remove_tree); remove_tree("$ENV{HOME}/.local/share/Trash/files/devices")'`.
Same thing for `du -s devices/`. Same thing for `du -sch ~/.local/share/Trash/`
Other commands

```
$ cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/
$ ls -ldi 
8131921 drwxr-xr-x 3 theking theking 4096 Mar 17 19:43 .
$ cd reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/
$ ls -dli
8131926 drwxr-xr-x 3 theking theking 4096 Mar 17 19:43 .


$ find .local/share/Trash/files/ -maxdepth 1 -delete
find: cannot delete `.local/share/Trash/files/devices': Directory not empty
find: cannot delete `.local/share/Trash/files/': Directory not empty
```

I don't want it stuck in my trash forever!

Note: I was making a crude backup of a computer by simply using `scp`, and but I ran out of space and then this happened.

Comment: Please show us the command you tried to delete it with and the error it gave you. What does `rm -rf devices` do?

Comment: Please also add the output of `ls -dli devices` and `ls -dli devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/`

Comment: The first command should have been `ls -ldi devices`, not `device`. I am trying to see if these are actually hard links (the same inode). However, be aware that if this is a large directory, `rm -rf` will take a long time but will eventually work. If the issue here is circular links, you will get an error message about infinite recursion. If there's no error message, just let `rm -rf` run its course.

Comment: @terdon: I thought Linux (Ubuntu, at least) doesn't allow hard-linked directories?

Comment: @saiarcot895 no it doesn't, good point.

Comment: Can you change the first block of code in your question with `ls -l` output?

Comment: I'm just assuming you tried with the nautilus built-in "empty trash" button ? (maybe they thought of that kind of things when writing nautilus^^)

Comment: @MrVaykadji I did and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to change the name of the directory? Something like `~/.local/share/Trash/files$ mv devices foldertotrash`

Comment: @desuga I could rename it but nautilus and rm still fail.

Comment: Have you tried `~/.local/share/Trash/files$ unlink devices`?

Comment: What is inside ~/.local/share/Trash/info ?

Comment: unlink didn't work

Comment: Ok, what's the output of `type devices/ devices/reg-dummy devices/reg-dummy/subsystem devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices`?

Comment: Says not found for each of them

Comment: Hmm may be `fsck --fix-fixable` can help?

Comment: That wasn't a valid flag.

Comment: Says it isn't a directory. Where am I doing this from?

Comment: @PyRulez Can you try this: 1. First, to be safe, run `find ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/ -exec echo {} \;` and 2. Second, if the output did not show any important file, then run `find ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/ -exec rm {} \;` And the final step would be `find ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/ -empty -type d -delete`

Comment: I just noticed the bounty now, I thought you had forgotten this. You still haven't told us if you've tried simoly letting any of these commands run for a while. If it's a big directory, deleting it could take quite a long while. Did you ever try the `rm -rvf` I suggested? Was there any output?

Answer (score 3):

The output of `ls -ldi` will show the inode number of the directory.  If the directory within the directory really has the same inode number as its ancestor, rather than just the same name, then your filesystem is corrupt and you will need to boot into rescue mode and fsck it.

Answer (score 1):

I still think that `rm -rf` will work if you give it enough time but if not, one or both of these should:

```
perl -e 'use File::Path qw(remove_tree); 
        remove_tree("$ENV{HOME}/.local/share/Trash/files/devices")'`
```

```
find .local/share/Trash/files/ -delete
```

You can make sure that *something* is happening if you use `rm -rfv ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices` at least that will let you know that files are being deleted.

Anyway, this can't be a hardlink problem (despite my very wrong comment) because directories can't be hardlinked under Linux. In general, when you have infinite recursion, as can happen with softlinks, you will get a message to that effect, that does not appear to happen.

The other possibility I can think of is that the Trash folder is some strange system of its own. I don't really know how it works, I never use it. However, you might have better luck deleting the top level files directly instead of targeting the problematic directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

You should also try emptying the Trash folder from the GUI, just select Trash and click on "Empty Trash", see if that works.

Comment: They both failed. Question revised.

Comment: @PyRulez how large is this directory? Neither the perl script nor the `rm` will produce any output. How long did they run for? I also updated the `find` command, the previous one was wrong, sorry. Have a look at the updated answer. Finally, we're working blind here. Please update your question with the output of `ls -l` where you have used `ls`, also show the result of `du -sch ~/.local/share/Trash/` so we know the size.

Comment: I couldn't find the size.

Comment: @PyRulez try `du -sch ~/.local/share/Trash/` that will give you the size. And please add all the stuff the various comments have asked for, they're needed so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: @tedron I have been.

Comment: @PyRulez you must have missed a few (fair enough, there have been many). We need the `ls -l` output instead of `ls`, we need the `du -sch ~/.local/share/Trash/` and we need the `ls -ldi   ~/.local/share/Trash/devices ~/.local/share/Trash/devices/devices/reg-dummy/subsystem/devices/` you ran it on `device` instead of devices. We also need to know how long you let the `rm -rf` command to run and whether you have tried emptying the trash from the GUI.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13717/discussion-between-terdon-and-pyrulez)

Comment: @PyRulez OK, we can now be sure you don't have a recursion problem, these are separate files. You still haven't told us how long you have waited for the commands to finish. Based on the timing of your edits, you haven't waited long. If you have a huge directory with millions of files, it may well take a few _hours_ to delete, don't expect results in seconds. Try leaving the computer on running `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` and go to sleep, see if it's done in the morning. Also clarify whether you've tried deleting them from the Trash folder in the file manager GUI, the "Empty Trash" button.

Comment: @PyRulez Have you tried creating another directory named `devices`, then moving it to overwrite the problematic one? Like this: `mkdir ~/devices`; `mv ~/devices ~/.local/share/Trash/files/`

Answer (score 0):

(I am confident this will work and as I am going to travel right now, I will leave this as an answer that I can delete in the future if it does not work.)

1. First, to be safe, run

   ```
   find ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/ -exec echo {} \;
   ```
2. Second, if the output of "1" did not show any important file, then run

   ```
   find ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/ -exec rm {} \;
   ```
3. The final step would be

   ```
   find ~/.local/share/Trash/files/devices/ -empty -type d -delete
   ```